# How not to inherit some function in the interface?

Tags: c#

I am having one interface which contains suppose 10-methods and it is inheriting to the class say class1.My requirement is i do not want to inherit 2-method into class1 .so how it is possible in c#.net

Comment: It's not, at least not in the way you're expecting.  If a class implements an interface, it has to implement *the entire* interface.  (That's what makes it an interface... it's a contract of functionality supplied by the class.)  If you want to pick and choose which parts to implement, then you want multiple smaller interfaces.  Attempting to apply an interface to a class which isn't actually described by that interface is a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: You can make your class1 abstract or inherit but throw NotSupportedException inside.

Comment: @Diryboy: Still a violation of Liskov Substitution.  The objects should accurately describe the functionality they expose.  Interfaces and abstract classes aren't just dumping grounds for functionality which may or may not be needed.

Comment: Change the interface so it matches your requirement...?

Comment: @David I agree with `NotSupportException` is a violation of the LS, but making it `abstract` wouldn't in itself.

Comment: @David You're right, but sometimes this happens, say `Stream`.

Comment: Regarding violating LS, developers _never_ [do that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), right? I agree though, if you can avoid having to throw the exception, or violating LS, that's best. I think Paolo's answer is a good idea if possible to implement. I think though we really need a better understanding of what Subhransu is trying to do; there's not enough context to provide a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could split your interface in 2, and have your class implement only one of them:

```
public interface Ifc1 {
    void Method1();
}
public interface Ifc2 {
    void Method2();
}
class Cls1 : Ifc1 {
    // now you need to implement Method1 only
}
```

Or you can throw a `NotImplementedException` in `Method2`:

```
class Cls1 : Ifc1 {
    public void Method2() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'd go for the first option, if possible.

If you throw an exception you will only find out that the method is not supported when you invoke it. You will have to catch the exception, and the code you'll write will have to deal with this, and will not be so clean.

If you split interfaces, instead, your class will just not have the method you don't want to implement.

Comment: The interface should be split up. Don't throw an exception, the fact you implement the interface states that you support all the behaviour defined by the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mix and match system.

Your class should implement the entire interface, as there is really no other choice within the context of your question.  The other answers can give you guidance on altering what may be incorrect semantics established by the designer of the interface.

Your class implements the interface, BUT your class itself is dependent on a future implementor actually doing the work.

You class should derive from a class that contains abstract functions.  Those abstract functions will be 'called' in your classes implementation of the interface.  But since your class contains unresolved abstract contents, it will not be directly instantiatable

UNTIL, another class inherits from your class, and either concretely implements the abstract functions or in an alternate, and - likely, scenario in the near term, throws non supported exception.

In this way, you can implement what you can without violating any principles, but pass on the fundamental conflict to a to be determined class.  In this way you make a forward step, but then sidestep the conflict.  Future implementors can rely on your forward step being a correct foundational move, but must resolve and reverse sidestep your lateral movement, to make an metaphor.